# Source property of Silverlight object

Tags: silverlight

```
    <div id="silverlightControlHost" >
    <object id="idThObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">

        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/MySolution.xap"/>

        <!--<param name="source" value="http://www.mysite.com/ClientBin/MySolution.xap"/> **NOT WORK**-->

         ...
</div>
```

Hi to ALL !

My Silverlight object exist on sever side in folder and when I try to load it like this : `<param name="source" value="http://www.mysite.com/ClientBin/WebSolution.xap" />`
This is **doesn't work**, but it I load this locally :
`<param name="source" value="ClientBin/MySolution.xap"/>`, **it's work fine**.
So what can I do to load my *.xap file from server or I don't have any chance to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have added the required mimetypes for silverlight in IIS on the server.

map the following.

- **.xap**     application/x-silverlight-app
- **.xaml**    application/xaml+xml
- **.xbap**    application/x-ms-xbap

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change any values of any type in html code. Visual Studio 2010 create standard template :

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="font-size: small;color: red;">
    <object id="idThObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/WebSolution.xap"/>
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" 
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
        </a>
    </object><iframe id='_sl_historyFrame' style='visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px'></iframe></div>
```

Only one point : provider of my site yahoo.com. So by default this guys don't use IIS.
So you think this is problem ? That Apache doesn't know this :
 **< ...data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2"/>**
look like I have to move to another provider, which support IIS.